# How to call Power Query M function from external Workbook?

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query, microsoft-powerbi

If I have an Excel workbook that is available online and this workbook contains a couple of spreadsheets and some Power Query M functions, is it possible to invoke these functions from another Workbook?

I know how to load the workbook with `Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents("url"))` but this only lists the available spreadsheets and tables, but not the available functions.

My workbook is publicly available and I want to access the functions without special authorization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported. However, it is possible to store your M scripts in a text file and run them.

1. Copy the contents of the query (from the Advanced Editor) into a file.
2. Use this to access the contents of that file: `= Text.FromBinary(File.Contents("path to your file"))`. Lets call this step `Source`.
3. Use `Expression.Evaluate(Source, #shared)` to evaluate that query. `Expression.Evaluate` will interpret a text value as code. `#shared` contains the list of all queries, functions, and constants in your code; it does not contain your current query's steps, however.

If you are mixing this with other data sources then you may need to either set the privacy levels for each source or disable privacy levels entirely, which you can do through the Options dialog under the Privacy section. Keep in mind that using this technique on unknown files on the internet when privacy levels are disabled may result in your data being leaked or exfiltrated.